# How to make an argument function which subtracts numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want the first number to be positive, like 10-20-30, not -10-20-30

```js
function substractAll() {
  var sum = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    sum -= arguments[i]
  }
  console.log(sum)
}
substractAll(10, 20, 30)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by setting `sum` to the first number instead of `0`, then loop over the remaining numbers.

```js
function substractAll() {
  var sum = arguments[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    sum -= arguments[i]
  }
  console.log(sum)
}
substractAll(10, 20, 30)
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar for the easiest solution

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the first argument first in the parameter list:

```js
function substractAll(initial, ...rest) {
  var sum = initial;
  for (var i = 0; i < rest.length; i++) {
    sum -= rest[i];
  }
  console.log(sum)
}
substractAll(10, 20, 30)
```

Or use `.reduce`, and depend on the initial value for the `.reduce` callback being the first accumulator, the only positive value, thanks @JaromandaX:

```js
function substractAll(...args) {
  const sum = args.reduce((a, b) => a - b);
  console.log(sum)
}
substractAll(10, 20, 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the first argument to sum as positive and then iterate the other arguments starting the for loop at index = 1:

```js
function substractAll(){
    var sum = 0;
    sum = arguments[0];
    for(let i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
        sum -= arguments[i]
    }
    console.log(sum)
}
substractAll (10, 20, 30)
```